# What does 'say' and 'ws.run task' in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I have to work on a vbs script. I have to admit that I have only c# experience and no clue about the following, what from my point of view is more SysAdmin Powerhell VBS-scripting.

1. For what stands 'say' here or in general? vbcrlf seems to be some kind of constant that puts the cursor to the beginning of a new line?

   ```
   say(vbcrlf)

   say("Some text...")

   ws.Run "C:\whatever.exe /PACK-* /SEND /Q", , True

   say(vbcrlf)
   ```
2. What does the ws.run task here? Just starts and run the scsript.exe?

   ```
   set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

   if ucase(right(wscript.fullname,11)) = "WSCRIPT.EXE" then

   task = "cscript.exe " & chr(34) & wscript.scriptfullname & chr(34)

   ws.run task

   wscript.quit

   end if
   ```

Thank you for any help on that!

Edit:

Problem is that the script runs like a charm on XP, but not on Win7. I think it must have something to do with the spaces in the path.
Here is the exact path I'm dealing with. Do I need to enclose them with additional double quotes or is chr(34) the way to go?

```
    ws.Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\whatever.exe /PACK-* /SEND /Q", , True
```

Edit:

Ok, I got it->

```
    ws.Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\whatever.exe"" /PACK-* /SEND /Q", , True
```

Comment: Today the same question arose to me when checking the tool [*MsiDiff*](http://dennisbareis.com/msidiff.htm) which is a part of *MakeMsi*. This tool uses also the [REXX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rexx) language which has the `say` keyword. I think it's just a handy abbreviation.

Answer (score 1):

`vbCrLf` is a pre-defined string constant consisting of a carriage return and a linefeed:

```
>> WScript.Echo Asc(vbCrLf), Asc(Right(vbCrLf, 1))
>>
13 10
```

see [String Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh277t8e%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

`say` isn't native VBScript; it must be a user-defined Sub:

```
>> Sub say(x) : WScript.Echo x : End Sub
>> say "pipapo"
>>
pipapo
```

(The param list () in your sample violate the rule: Don't use param list () when calling a Sub)

`.Run` is a method (function) of the WScript.Shell object; it executes/runs an external process. In your example it is used (as a Sub) to re-start the script with the **c**script.exe host (instead of **w**script.exe).

see [WshShell object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), [.Run method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

**P.S.**

If you use .Run (or. Exec), it is a very good idea to build the first/strCommand parameter into a variable for inspection and tests from a command prompt. The argument "Pointlessly create a variable to use extra memory, slow down the script, and to make script harder to read" became obsolete shortly after clay replaced stone for information storage.

Comment: Thank you all so far for your input. Your are bringing me into the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

```
'Connects to COM object WScript.Shell
set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

'Testing what script engine is running the script, if the GUI one then do the following. wscript object is always available in wscript/cscript run scripts
if ucase(right(wscript.fullname,11)) = "WSCRIPT.EXE" then

'Pointlessly create a variable to use extra memory, slow down the script, and to make script harder to read
task = "cscript.exe " & chr(34) & wscript.scriptfullname & chr(34)

'Run the current script in the console version of the scripting host
ws.run task

'quits the script leaving the console version to run
wscript.quit

end if
```